# How to vectorise in SAS/IML?

Tags: sas-iml

Suppose I have

```
  proc iml;
  x = {1,2,3};
```

I am interested in computing CDF ('F',1,2, ....) for every element of x. Of course, I can write a loop, but I would like to know the smart way of doing it, i.e. vectorise?

I tried to google but could not find anything, any takers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When SAS/IML calls Base SAS functions, you can usually pass in a vector in place of the scalar arguments.  In your example, it's as easy as 
c = cdf("Normal", x);

For more information, you can read about [how to call Base SAS functions from SAS/IML.](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2010/09/08/calling-base-sas-functions-from-sasiml-programs/)
If the need arises, [you can also pass in vectors for MULTIPLE arguments](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/11/21/call-base-sas-functions-with-vectors-of-arguments/), provided that the vectors are the same size.

Comment: couldn't believe the person who helped me is you! thanks a lot Rick!

Comment: Rick, how do I use SAS/IML in the university edition? (or can't I?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178729/why-do-i-get-the-following-error-when-i-try-to-implementan-example-from-wicklin

i cannot get the following code from your book to work.

Comment: Put 
PROC IML;
at the top of the program.  The University Edition supports PROC IML, but not SAS/IML Studio. Your code is not working because there is no version of R installed on the virtual machine (the vApp).